# Обновление доставки после ввода адреса Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На странице заказа woocommerce обновляет варианты доставки после ввода города.

Как добавить в эту функцию поле адреса?

Нужно чтобы после ввода адреса, обновлялись варианты доставка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте скрипт на страницу чекаута и замените `input[name^="your-field"]` на нужный селектор для вашего поля:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name^="your-field"]', function() { 
            $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```